# How do I compare times using an if statement in python from a csv file

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to build a program which reads dates from a csv file. I then wish to compare them using an if statement

However every time I attempt this in every way I have tried it results in a lot of errors

I get the time by slicing from the csv file where a column consists of both the time and date [Device Timestamp]

Dates_and_times = pd.Series(readings[Device Timestamp]

Reading_times = dates_and_times.str.slice(0, 10)

I then attempt the if statement to sort the reading times into categories

If 11:00:00 < reading_times <=16:00:00
Afternoon_reading+=1

Then I get hit with the following errors

Invalid syntax (:)

And a lot more at runtime including cannot convert between instances of str and int etc

Can someone please tell me how to put these times in a suitable format to be used in an if statement

Sample date in the csv: "05/11/2019 12:20:00"

Comment: Provide an example of how a timestamp looks in the file. In any case, the answer will probably be using the module `datetime`.

Comment: Okay here it is for the first row Device Timestamp = 05/11/2019 12:20:00

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for possible format:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('05/11/2019 12:20:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

The concept is to describe how your date looks using characters the the module `datetime` understands.

Comment: Thankyou, but where and how would I implement this into my code

Comment: Also I need to convert all times to this format, not just one how would I do that

Comment: When you read the CSV file, you should end up with a list of strings, each string representing a date. Call this line for each one of the strings, instead of the hard-coded string I put in.

Comment: Can you please show me an example like this instead of the hard worked one

Comment: I managed to solve this using a for loop for each element of the csv file

Comment: For x in times_and_dates x=datetime.strptime(x, ‘%m/%d/%Y %H:%m’) thanks so much for the advice